# Не распечатывается дата в файл

Tags: bash

В файл не распечатывается полная комбинация подстановок:

```
echo $D$M$Y00 > out.txt
```

Заданы

```
data = $(date +"%D-%M-%Y")
D = ${data:3:2}
M = ${data:0:2}
Y = ${data:12:4}
```

Дальше вывожу на печать в файл следующие команды:

```
echo $Y$M$D00 > sometext.txt
```

Но в итоговом файле получается `202105` вместо `2021052100`.

Пробовал комбинацию

```
echo $Y$M $D 00
```

В таком случае все печатается как надо - `202105 21 00`.

Comment: Используйте ${Y}00 так как нули баш считает частью переменной, которой нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

стандарт [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) говорит по этому поводу:

> The simplest form for parameter expansion is:
>
> ```
> ${parameter}
> ```
>
> The value, if any, of parameter shall be substituted.
>
> The parameter name or symbol can be enclosed in braces, which are optional except for positional parameters with more than one digit or when parameter is a name and is followed by a character that could be interpreted as part of the name. The matching closing brace shall be determined by counting brace levels, skipping over enclosed quoted strings, and command substitutions.
>
> **If the parameter is not enclosed in braces, and is a name, the expansion shall use the longest valid name (see XBD Name), whether or not the variable represented by that name exists**.

перевод выделенного (это касается непосредственно вопроса):

> если параметр не заключен в фигурные скобки, и он является именем, то для подстановки должно использоваться самое длинное из допустимых имён, вне зависимости от того, существует ли переменная с таким именем.

---

т.е., программа *bash* в приведённом примере действует в полном согласии с буквой и духом стандарта posix: строку `$D00` пытается интерпретировать как отсылку к переменной с именем `D00` (значение для которой в вашем скрипте, понятно, не установлено).

чтобы избежать подобных конфузов, имеет смысл не пренебрегать полной формой записи параметров и писать `${x}`, а не сокращённо `$x`.